# Difference in Start and End times grouping by hour in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

My table has info similar to below

```
Emp  Date       START_TIME            END_TIME             Code     Minutes
---  --------   -------------------   -------------------  ----     -------
 E1  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:55:00 AM  11/1/2012 7:01:00 AM  C1       6
 E1  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:57:00 AM  11/1/2012 8:01:00 AM  C2       64
 E2  11/1/2012  11/1/2012 6:57:00 AM  11/1/2012 8:00:00 AM  C2       63
 E1  11/2/2012  11/2/2012 7:35:00 AM  11/2/2012 8:01:00 AM  C1       26
```

Expected Output is

```
Date       Code  Range                        Minutes
---------  ----  -----------------------      ------- 
11/1/2012   C1   6:00:00 AM-7:00:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C1   7:00:00 AM-8:00:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C2   6:30:00 AM-7:00:00 AM           30 
11/1/2012   C2   7:00:00 AM-7:30:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C2   7:30:00 AM-8:00:00 AM           60
11/1/2012   C2   8:00:00 AM-8:30:00 AM           30
11/2/2012   C1   7:30:00 AM-8:00:00 AM           25
11/2/2012   C1   8:00:00 AM-8:30:00 AM           1
```

I want to group by date, and code with total time spent in a span of 60 minutes each. And the limitation I have is to achieve this using select statements

Comment: Have you tried any code?

Comment: [How to ask about homework](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first. Ask about *specific* problems with your *existing* implementation. Admit that the question is homework. Be aware of school policy regarding outside help. Never use code you don't understand.

Comment: I'm not understanding where the 30 minutes on the third row of the expected output is coming from.  "total time spent",,, as a total from the minutes column?   "in a span of 60 minutes each" ...   each *what*? each row of output... the first two rows in the expected result show a "range" of 60 minutes, the remaining rows are a "range" of 30 minutes.   Are you referring to "range" when you say "span", or are you meaning a "span" between START_TIME and WORK_TIME. This isn't a SQL problem yet, it's a specification problem. Without a clear spec, we don't have any test cases to test against.

Comment: you expected output logic is not clear to me. why there is  30 min difference between each timeframe? is it a requirement? and how come the minutes difference in last row becomes 1?